# syntactic/semantic extensions to typescript with VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

i have some "extensions" to the typescript language which can be realized with the internal APIs exposed by compiler for re-writing the AST; and tools like 'tslint' can handle some of the deeper semantic issues....

my question is how this all might integrate with typescript language support in the VS code editor....  am i still able to rewrite AST trees as i'm editing a source file???

as a somewhat concrete example, imagine if my .ts file contained what in effect were "macro directives" which syntactically look like a typescript function call with constants as parameters....  i've seen examples online where this call-expression is replaced with other syntactic elements within the AST...

but here too, what happens when i'm sitting in the VS code editor entering a something like 'directive(arg1, arg2)', which *expands* into semantically valid typescript but would otherwise result in various errors in the editor???

said another way, can i transform the source code *before* the editor itself does its own thing vis-a-vis highlighting errors, code completion, etc???

Comment: here's a specific example:  i want to create a macro that i would invoke as `use('foo.Bar')` in my typescript source file...  this macro would expand to a much more complex set of `import` / `export` statements used in a very specific pattern....  given that i'm sitting in a typescript-aware editor that is incrementally parsing as i type, i'd like to ensure this macro is programmatically expanded *before* the editor has a chance to analyze the sources....  i've read about transforms using the compiler APIs, but wasn't sure whether that whole mechanism is live when i'm in the editor